# How to make a button blink/flash on mouse click?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I am very new to AS3 , right now I am trying to make a button( made in the fla with the shape tool) to blink 3 times when press like a car indicator. I have converted it into a symbol and currently trying to program the class itself (I am not sure if I am meant to code the symbol class or the main class that is directly connected to the fla). Right now I have 3 class made 2 triangle (Rblinker and Lblinker) and "MAIN".

Biggest problem atm is that I can't seem to get the buttons to blink on a mouse click, can any body help? thank you

Right now my code for "Rblinker" looks like this.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent

public class Rblinker extends MovieClip {

    public var timer:Timer =  new Timer(1000,3);
    public var blink:Boolean = true;
    timer.start();


    public function Rblinker() {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.click, clickaction);


        function clickaction(e:MouseEvent):void{
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerAction);
            this.alpha = 1;
    }


    function timerAction(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (!blink){
                this.alpha = 1;
                } 
            else{
                this.alpha = 0;
                }

        blink = !blink;
        }
    }
}
```

Both blinker will be have the same code. also would like to just use the AC3 language only

Comment: init the timer in the click handler

Comment: Ok so i removed the public var and placed them in the `public function Rblinker()`. `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.click, clickaction);` received an error 1119, i do not understand this error.

Comment: In an event handler, the scope is different, so `this` means something else. Easiest solution for you is not to nest the handler inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Rblinker extends MovieClip {

    public var timer:Timer =  new Timer(1000,3);//tick every second, 3 times total


    public function Rblinker() {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickaction);

        //add listeners in the constructor
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerAction);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
    }

    function clickaction(e:Event):void {
        //on the click, hide it to start, then start the timer
        this.visible = false;
        timer.reset(); //reset first so it always goes 3 times even if it's clicked again before finishing
        timer.start();
    }


    function timerAction(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
       //toggle the visibility of this sprite every timer tick
       this.visible = !this.visible;

       //or, if you want to keep using alpha (so the button can still be clicked when not visible)
       this.alpha = alpha > 0 ? 0 : 1;   //this is an inline if statment
    }

    function timerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
        //now that the timer is totally done, make sure the item is visible again
        this.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however there is an error 1119 static reference at `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.click, clickaction);` seems like i can't put event listeners in the class itself or am i wrong ? @Marton_Pallagi commented above saying the listener shouldn't be nested in the constructor.

Comment: Your problem is that "click" should be all caps.  I just copy and pasted from your question and didn't notice until now.